# Что не так с иконками?

Tags: css3, html5, icon

Сохранил иконки с проекта. Начал их конвертировать в icomoon. при добавлении иконок в icomoon вышло такое сообщение

> "Strokes get ignored when generating fonts. You can convert them to
> fills to prevent this."(При создании шрифтов штрихи игнорируются. Вы
> можете преобразовать их в заливки, чтобы этого не произошло.)

. Хотя иконки видимы в сервисе.
Далее при генерации иконок вышло такое сообщение

> Strokes get ignored when generating fonts. You can convert them to
> fills to prevent this. Would you like to deselect icons containing
> strokes? (При создании шрифтов штрихи игнорируются. Вы можете
> преобразовать их в заливки, чтобы этого не произошло. Вы хотите
> отменить выбор значков, содержащих штрихи?)

Проигнорировав все сохранил подключил и попытался вставить в проект но они не отображаются на странице. Может ли быть проблема из-за этих сообщений и как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

> Strokes get ignored when generating fonts. You can convert them to
> fills to prevent this. Would you like to deselect icons containing
> strokes?

Ну собственно тут сказано что "strokes" (штрихи) будут проигнорированы при генерации шрита. Их нужно конвертировать в "fills" (заливки). Вам нужно конвертировать это при помощи Adobe Illustrator или чего-то другого что умеет работать с векторными файлами, подробнее можете прочесть на сайте Icomoon в [документации](https://icomoon.io/#docs/stroke-to-fill).

Comment: да я уже понял. сейчас попробую с помощью inkscape